# How to set image to ImageView using setImageURI inside a RecyclerView adapter?

Tags: java, android

I have a RecyclerView to display multiple images using an ImageView. An ArrayList of type Strings are passed into the adapter's constructor, the array contains the absolute file paths of the images.

I can set an ImageView using the same file path from an activity class using:

```
File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
imagePreview.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(f));
```

If I try this in the adapter's `onBindViewHolder()` method, nothing is displayed and no errors are thrown.

Here is the `onBindViewHolder()` method:

```java
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(getItemCount() > 0) {
        File file = new File(mFilePaths.get(position));
        holder.imagePreviewView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file));
    }
}
```

I don't think it is the ImageView causing problems because I can set the ImageView using `setImageResource()` and using a random photo file from my /drawable folder.

I have also tried using the Picasso library to no avail.

Appreciative of any help or direction, thanks.

**EDIT:**
Added in complete Adapter class.

```java
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder>{
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = ImageAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    // Member variables
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private final ArrayList<String> mFilePaths;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> filePaths) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mFilePaths = filePaths;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View mItemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_image, parent, false);
        return new ImageViewHolder(mItemView, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(getItemCount() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: " + mFilePaths.get(position));
            File file = new File(mFilePaths.get(position));
            holder.imagePreviewView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file));
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: getItemCount is 0");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFilePaths.size();
    }

    class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final ImageView imagePreviewView;
        final ImageAdapter mAdapter;

        public ImageViewHolder(View imageView, ImageAdapter adapter) {
            super(imageView);
            imagePreviewView = imageView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_preview);
            this.mAdapter = adapter;
        }
    }
}
```

**RE-EDIT:** `item_image.xml` added.

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_preview"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a right value in `Uri.fromFile(file)`? Does `holder.imagePreviewView` refer to a required `ImageView`? Is `getItemCount()` more than 0? Also you can refresh an image with a delay, for instance, by `new Handler().postDelayed()`.

Comment: @CoolMind the file in ```Uri.fromFile(file)``` has the exact same file path as the one I've tested outside of the adapter. Yes you're correct, ```holder.imagePreviewView``` is the ImageView in the layout for the adapter. ```getItemCount()``` is returning 1. I will look into refreshing image using the Handler you mentioned. I'm sort of new to that sort of thing, do you have any useful tutorials on Handler's? Thanks again.

Comment: Then try to set image or background (or size, etc.) with static data. For instance, `holder.imagePreviewView.setImageResource(...)`. If it doesn't change, then it will be a problem in `ViewHolder`. Instead of `Handler` you can also use any delay (for instance, `Thread` and switch to UI thread). Also, how do you call `onCreateViewHolder`? You can also try to redraw Image there (but only for testing).

Comment: @CoolMind I've just tried to use ```setImageResource``` using a static variable which holds a file in /drawable and it didn't change? Could possibly be my ```ViewHolder``` then? Here is my ```onCreateViewHolder``` method:
```final View mItemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_image, parent, false);
return new ImageViewHolder(mItemView, this); ```

Comment: @CoolMind I've added the complete Adapter class if you want to have a look. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! Please, add also `item_image.xml`. Maybe you should remove `if(getItemCount() > 0)`.

Comment: @CoolMind I've added ```item_image.xml```. I tried removing the if statement but still nothing, unfortunately.